# Python Box and Pointers in lists

Tags: python-3.x

I'm studying for my final semester written paper. I was taught to trace the mutations of lists using box and pointer diagrams. However there was one question I came across where my method didn't work.

```
#Main code 1
a = [1, 2]
b = [a, a]
c = a.copy()
c[0], a[1] = b[1], c[0] #replace this

#code A
##c[0]=b[1]
##a[1]=c[0]

#code B
##a[1]=c[0]
##c[0]=b[1]

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)

##Normal Output/Code B
##[1, 1]
##[[1, 1], [1, 1]]
##[[1, 1], 2]

##Code A output
##[1, [...]]
##[[1, [...]], [1, [...]]]
##[[1, [...]], 2]
```

The main code is written as it is, and the given answer is shown in `Normal Output`(proven by Python3 IDLE). When I did the tracing on paper, I thought that the code would produce `Code A output` instead.

> Is there any knowledge that I am missing out here?

Here are some other similar mutation questions that my method of tracing has worked in, but I can't draw any differences to why this behaviour is only seen in the first code.

```
#Code2 where switching line 3 like code 1 doesn't matter
a = [['a', 'b'], ['c'], 'd']
b = a[:-1]
a[1], b[0][1] = b[0], a[2] #switch this
print(a)
print(b)

##[['a', 'd'], ['a', 'd'], 'd']
##[['a', 'd'], ['c']]

#Code3 that has the same output even with a 1 liner replacement
a = [1,2,3]
b = [a,3,4]
a[2] = b
b[0][0] = b
a[0][1] = 99
a[2][0] = 5
#a[2],b[0][0],a[0][1],a[2][0]=b,b,99,5 #1 liner replacement
print(a)

#[[5, 99, 4], 2, [5, 99, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

An assignment statement has two parts, a left side and a right side.  The right side is calculated first, then the left side is calculated, then the right side is assigned to the left side, through tuple unpacking if necessary.

So `c[0], a[1] = b[1], c[0]` becomes `c[0], a[1] = (a, 1)`.  Then `c[0] = a`, then `a[1] = 1`

So you end up with the final result `c == [[1, 1], 2]` and `a == [1, 1]`, with `b == [a, a]` still.

A key thing to realize here is that `1, 2, 3` is the syntax for a tuple.

`a, b = 1, 2` and `a, b = (1, 2)` are exactly the same, it's just that in most contexts there are operators around that require you to parenthesize the tuple elements.

It's easier to follow that example if we give `a[0]` it's own variable name.  So

```
x = ['a', 'b']
a = [x, ['c'], 'd'] 
b = a[:-1]
```

Then `a[1], b[0][1] = b[0], a[2]` -> `a[1], b[0][1] = x, 'd'` -> `a[1] = x` and `x[1] = 'd'`.
So we end up with `x = ['a', 'd']`, `a = [x, x, 'd']` and `b = [x, ['c']]`.  The `['c']` isn't an `x` because the second list in `a` wasn't mutated, it was replaced in `a` but not in `b`.

Comment: Can I clarify that the order of assignation by Python is Then `c[0] = a`, then `a[1] = 1`, left to right for unpacking a tuple? I understand how ur edited answer for Code 2 works, and it turns out whichever order I do gets the same result.

All in all, I think I am rather uncomfortable with the fact that u could say  `a[1] = 1` without considering whether the `c[0]` could have changed to `b[1]`, which is actually `a` and hence my initial purpose to ask this question.